# how to downgrade GDB 7.6.1 to GDB 6.8?

Tags: 13.10, downgrade, gdb

I am using linux (ubuntu 13.10) for openfoam(free ware) which calculate the fluid motion.

Openfoam program is really uncomfortable to use, they even provide debug :)

So to me, I need to use GDB for debugging openfoam, But GDB 7.6 version

cause some problem to debugging openfoam ;(

I thought this is not a problem of GDB, just because of openfoam.

But I heard that GDB 6.8 didnt crash with openfoam debugging.

So I want to install GDB 6.8 for this.

But I dont know how to install GDB 6.8  in ubuntu 13.10 version.

and I cant find a any solution for this.

Please send me a solution for this (install GDB 6.8 instead of GDB 7.6)

thank you